# Python : Locking text file on NFS

Tags: python, python-2.7, nfs, file-locking, fcntl

I have a file `results.txt` on a server which is accessed by multiple VMs through NFS. A process runs on each of these VMs which reads the `results.txt` file and modifies it. If two processes, `A` and `B`, read the file at the same time, then modification of either A or B would be present in `results.txt` based on the order in which the processes write to the file.

If process `A` has a write lock over the file then process `B` would have to wait till the lock is released to read the `results.txt` file.

I have tried implementing this using Python:

```
import fcntl


f = open("/path/result.txt")
fcntl.flock(f,fcntl.LOCK_EX)
#code
```

It works as expected for files on the local disk.

but when I run try to lock a file on the mounted path, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lock.py", line 12, in <module>
    fcntl.flock(f,fcntl.LOCK_EX)
IOError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported
```

I tried `fcntl.fcntl` and `fcntl.flock` but got the same error. Is this an issue with the way I am using `fcntl`? Is any configuration required on the server where file is stored?

**Edit:**

This is how I am using `fcntl.fcntl`:

```
f= open("results.txt")
lockdata = struct.pack('hhllhh', fcntl.F_RDLCK,0,0,0,0,0)
rv = fcntl.fcntl(f, fcntl.F_SETLKW, lockdata)
```

The NFS server version is 3.

Comment: Could you paste the way you use `fcntl.fcntl()`?

Comment: @vmonteco, I have added the code snippet.

Comment: Does `fcntl.fcntl(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX)` work?

Comment: @vmonteco It doesn't give any error. But I don't think lock is being applied. I am able to run the script on the same file in two different sessions and none of them wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [flufl.lock](https://pythonhosted.org/flufl.lock/) most suited for my requirement.

Quoting the author from project [page](https://launchpad.net/flufl.lock):

> [...] O_EXCL is broken on NFS file systems, programs which rely on
>   it
>           for performing locking tasks will contain a race condition. The
>           solution for performing atomic file locking using a lockfile is to
>           create a unique file on the same fs (e.g., incorporating hostname and
>           pid), use link(2) to make a link to the lockfile. If link() returns
>           0, the lock is successful. Otherwise, use stat(2) on the unique file
>           to check if its link count has increased to 2, in which case the lock
>           is also successful.

Since it is not part of the standard library I couldn't use it. Also, my requirement was only a subset of all the features offered by this module.

The following functions were written based on the modules. Please make changes based on the requirements.

```
def lockfile(target,link,timeout=300):                                             
        global lock_owner                                                          
        poll_time=10                                                               
        while timeout > 0:                                                         
                try:                                                               
                        os.link(target,link)                                       
                        print("Lock acquired")                                      
                        lock_owner=True                                            
                        break                                                      
                except OSError as err:                                             
                        if err.errno == errno.EEXIST:                              
                                print("Lock unavailable. Waiting for 10 seconds...")
                                time.sleep(poll_time)                              
                                timeout-=poll_time                                 
                        else:                                                      
                                raise err                                          
        else:                                                                      
                print("Timed out waiting for the lock.") 

def releaselock(link):                          
        try:                                    
                if lock_owner:                  
                        os.unlink(link)         
                        print("File unlocked")   
        except OSError:                         
                print("Error:didn't possess lock.")
```

This is a crude implementation that works for me. I have been using it and haven't faced any issues. There are many things that can be improved though. Hope this helps.